# How should I evaluate the average order of $\sigma(n)$?

Tags: number-theory, analysis, analytic-number-theory

I was reading Apostol's book *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory,* and was trying to use the method introduced in this book to evaluate $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{1\leq m\leq n}\sigma(m),$ where $\sigma(m)$ is the sum of of all positive divisors of $m.$

Using the method in the book, I got
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{1\leq m\leq n}\sigma(m)&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{1\leq m\leq n}\sum_{d|m}d=
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{1\leq m\leq n}\sum_{d|m}\frac{m}{d}\\
&(*)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{\substack{d,q\\{1\leq dq\leq n}}}q=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{d\leq n}\sum_{q\leq\frac{n}{d}}q=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{d\leq n}\frac{1}{2}[\frac{n}{d}]([\frac{n}{d}]+1)\\
&=\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{d\leq n}(\frac{n}{d}+O(1))(\frac{n}{d}+O(1))
\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{d\leq n}\frac{n^2}{d^2}+O(1+\log n)\\&=\frac{\pi^2}{12}n+O(1+\log n), \quad \text{which is the correct answer.}
\end{align*}
But at step $(*)$, if I interchange the oder of $q$ and $d$ in the summation, I got something different
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{1\leq m\leq n}\sigma(m)&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{q\leq n}q\sum_{d\leq{\frac{n}{q}}}1=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{q\leq n}q[\frac{n}{q}]=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{q\leq n}q(\frac{n}{q}+O(1))\\
&=\sum_{q\leq n}1+O(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{q\leq n}q)=[n]+O(n)=n+O(n).
\end{align*}
The above expression I obtained using the second method is apparently not correct. But given my calculation at each step is correct, where did I go wrong with the second method? Will I essentially obtain the same result as in the first method?

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: @TravorLZH But I'm also multiplying $\frac{1}{n}$ in the front, after doing this it seems that the error term should be $O(n)$?

Comment: Both methods are correct. However, the second method doesn't tell you anything other than $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{1 \leq m \leq n} \sigma(m) = O(n)$, since $n + O(n) = O(n)$. So the second method merely gives an upper bound for this sum, rather than an asymptotic.

Comment: @PeterHumphries Oh I see, that makes sense. Originally I thought these two methods should give the same result, but it turns out both of them are correct. I now understand this, and many thanks for your explanation:)